# How to extract the numbers from json path using scala

Tags: json, scala

My response will be like:

`{
  "code" : 201,
  "message" : "Your Quote Id is 353541551"
}`

From this above response I have to extract the number 353541551 alone, so I tried with the basic scala snippets. I tried the following:

```
.check((status is 201),(jsonPath("Your Quote Id is(//d{9})").saveAs("quoteid")))
```

And another snippet:

```
.check((status is 201),(jsonPath("$.message.([0-9]+)").saveAs("quoteid")))
```

But both didn't work

Please help me out to extract the numbers

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Are you using [gatling](http://www.gatling.io)? Also, welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than write "both didn't work," I suggest that you include the specific, reproducible error. Otherwise, I, like, I suspect, others, won't actually try to help you since they can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes am using gatling...........and also the error I got was                                               > jsonPath(Your Quote Id is(//d{9})).find(0).exists failed, coul      1 (100.0%)
d not extract:  could not extract : `$' expected but `Y' found

Answer (score 0):

Try to use spary json; https://github.com/spray/spray-json

You can define json data structure using scala case class and define custom apply/unapply methods if required.

```
case class JsonResponse(code: Int, message: String)
object JsonResponse { implicit val f = JsonFormat2(JsonResponse.apply)}
```

you can use scala Regex to pattern match the string to extract the required value.